# How to add exclude folder in windows 7 for Microsoft essentials

Tags: c#, python, powershell, shell, command

Basically

I can't run this code because of the permissions.

```
REG ADD 'HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Exclusions\Paths' / v " + path + " / t REG_DWORD / d 0 / f
```

I found a way during research doing it by SetACL.exe process is quite long

1. Back-up ownership
2. Set owner ship
3. Unlock the registry key
4. Add the folder with with above code
5. Lock the key for read only
6. recover ownership

Each step is confusing and require more efforts to understand of working with this SETACL.exe

So my question is rather than doing with SETAcl.exe is there any efficient or easier way to do this ?
It could be powershell or it could be some command line or some other script .NET , Python etc.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell (run as Administrator):

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Exclusions\Paths' -Name 'TheExcludedPath' -Value 0 -Type DWord -Force
```

Comment: Well , i tried and i had exception because i am trying to run the code through .NET but This could be useful  most likely for the exception PowerShell is not installed in Windows 7 as default .. will give a try again after installing PowerShell manually. thanks again.

Comment: Set-ItemProperty : Requested registry access is not allowed.

Comment: @OzgurOz Are you running this as Administrator?

Comment: Yes its running as Administrator

Comment: @OzgurOz Start Regedit.exe and check the permissions on that key. Also, try shutting down the AV software and see if then you have permissions

Comment: Special permissions ticked only.